# Notification send to user in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets

Following code is for back end which is implemented in NodeJS for socket call.

```
const socket = require('socket.io');

let Users = [];

module.exports = function (server) {
    const io = socket.listen(server);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        socket.on('socket-call', function (userId) {
            Users[userId] = socket.id; 
            socket.broadcast.emit('socket-call', {msg: 'login call'});
        }); 
 });
};
```

I want to send notification message to particular user as which id has been passed from front end. But it send notification to all user.

I have tried with following, It is not working. Please suggest me for the solution.

```
socket.broadcast.to(Users[userId]).emit('socket-call', {msg: 'login call'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
socket.emit('socket-call', userId);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.